# How to create a line graph in R from a matrix

Tags: r, excel

I am a complete beginner to R.  I would like to know how to create a line graph based on the below image.  It is an excel file, and I do not know how to get R to interact with it.  I have tried some googling on the topic but I really don't know anything about R to make sense of the help provided.

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("C:/users/myname/downloads/BCLDatabase_online_v2.4.xlsx"")
matplot(t(matrix_name), type = "l")
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Remove the double quote at the end and assign the results from the read statement to a variable: `df <- read_excel( "C:/users/myname/downloads/BCLDatabase_online_v2.4.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```r
library(readxl)
my_data <- read_excel("C:/users/myname/downloads/BCLDatabase_online_v2.4.xlsx", sheet = 1)
M <- as.matrix(my_data[,-1])
matplot(x = my_data$Year, y = M, type = "l")
```

Repeat for each sheet/tab (or, put the whole thing in a `for` loop, if you have set up some appropriate way to store the plots (e.g. you could use `par(mfrow=c(2,3))` first to set up a 2x3 plotting grid).

Comment: That definitely did something: 

Error in matplot(x = my_data$Year, y = M, type = "l") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have same number of rows

My excel file has 5 tabs, each with headers in row 1, and columns a, b, c, d, e, are year, australia, japan, mexico, usa, euro respectively.

Ideally I would like to be able to plot them all on one graph for each tab.

Comment: I shouldn't have included `t()`. edited.